# Xamarin Selecting An Image From Gallery And Displaying It In The Listview Adapter

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have few questions. I have a listview,listview adapter and an activity that the listview is in. And there is a button for each listview column and it lets you choose an image from the gallery.

So all listview's objects are defined in the Adapter and you cant create the gallery selection from the Adapter. So im creating it with accessing to the activity.

1-) Can i pass my holder objects to OnActivityResult method? That would solve all the problems

2-) So how do i choose the image and then pass it to my adapter? I tried using a static variable for image uri but its not synchronizated. In my adapter class

```
public class Duzenle_Adapter
{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public static Android.Net.Uri static_uri;
 public Duzenle_Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Yemek_Liste> objects,Duzenle_Activity d) : base(context, resource, objects)
    {
        this.c = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.yemekler = objects;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (inflater == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        }
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }
        //List<Yemek_Liste> yemekler = new List<Yemek_Liste>();
        //yemekler = db.selectItem();
        Tutan_Duzenle tut = new Tutan_Duzenle(convertView);
        tut.img.SetImageResource(yemekler[position].Get_ImageID());//default image


        if (!tut.res_degis.HasOnClickListeners)
        {
            tut.res_degis.Click += delegate
            {

                d.tikla();
                tut.img.SetImageURI(static_uri);
            };
        }
   }
```

And in activity class ;

```
public class Duzenle_Activity:Activity
{
  ......

  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {

            Settings_Adapter.static_uri = data.Data;


        }
    }
    public void tikla()
    {
        var imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(
            Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);

    }
}
```

So it calls the function when the gallery opens up the adapter tries to set image uri to none.

Thanks in the advance. Sorry for the complicated post

Edit: Or is there anyway to wait for the "tikla" method to complete? That could solve the problem too.

Edit 2: Or can we customize the onActivityResult ? we can send the holder object as paramaters maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Activity(Label = "Duzenle_Activity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Duzenle_Activity : Activity
{
    ListView listView1;
    List<Yemek> objects = new List<Yemek>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ChooseImageLayout);

        listView1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            objects.Add(new Yemek { ButtonText = $"Select {i}" });
        }

        listView1.Adapter = new Duzenle_Adapter(this, objects);


    }

    public void tikla()
    {
        var imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(
            Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);

    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            Duzenle_Adapter adapter = ((Duzenle_Adapter)listView1.Adapter);
            adapter.SelectedYemek.ImageUri = data.Data;
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            //or listView1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

public class Yemek
{
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }
    public Android.Net.Uri ImageUri { get; set; }
}

public class Duzenle_Adapter : BaseAdapter<Yemek>
{
    List<Yemek> yemeklerList;
    Duzenle_Activity activity;
    int selectedPosition=-1;

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return yemeklerList.Count;
        }
    }

    public override Yemek this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return yemeklerList[position];
        }
    }

    public Duzenle_Adapter(Context context, List<Yemek> objects)
    {
        this.activity = (Duzenle_Activity)context;
        this.yemeklerList = objects;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            convertView = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.yemekler_cell, parent, false);

        var yemekler = yemeklerList[position];

        var btn = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btn.Text = yemekler.ButtonText;
        btn.Tag = position; //store item position in Tag

        if (!btn.HasOnClickListeners)
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        var imgView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        if (yemeklerList[position].ImageUri == null)
            imgView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        else
            imgView.SetImageURI(yemeklerList[position].ImageUri);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedPosition = (int)((Button)sender).Tag; //store selected item position
        activity.tikla();
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {

        return yemeklerList[position].GetHashCode(); //not used
    }

    public Yemek SelectedYemek
    {
        get
        {
            return yemeklerList[selectedPosition];
        }
    }
}
```

yemekler_cell.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:text="Select Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ChooseImageLayout.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the code with more detailed sample but still recommend considering doing it via adapter

Comment: Im allready doing it like that i mean thats where my problem begins. I have holder objects for every row in listview and change the image buttons are in holder object too. So it needs to be spesific for every holder object. Im calling the tikla from adapter class (tikla is in the activity) but i cant set image to that row's holder's imageview. So i call the tikla from Edit_Adapter class and tikla is in the Edit_Activity class.

Comment: I cant display the gallery selection window on adapter class it must be an activity i believe?

Comment: Please provide the source code. Unfortunately I don't have time to recreate the whole project.

Comment: Not enough. Where is the Yemek_Liste class? What your adpter is derived from (ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter)? You pass resource ID to inflate view. Where is xaml for this view? What is Tutan_Duzenle class? How you connect adapter to listview? I don't see any listview in xaml at all. GetView doesn't return any view. If you want quick help please provide all required code (ideally the project in dropbox or github)

Comment: ok, I recreated all your code. Updated my answer for working solution

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow but it seems like it will solve it . Thanks a lot .

Comment: You are welcome. This is based on assumption that you are not going to add or remove items. If you do you might store either guid for the row or actual reference to Yemek instead of position.

Comment: Everything is okay now except its kinda lagging when scrolling in listview. Images i set are not big sized images.

Comment: I don't know what your cells content really is. When you use custom cells it gets slow. May be you can use any of standard cell. One more comment: You wanted a button inside cell. I wouldn't do that. I would use ListItem_Selected event on list instead of button handler. Then you don't need a button and your cell gets simpler

Comment: I get what you mean but i need few buttons so listitem selected wont be enough for me. Its not about button though without any images changed its fast when i change the images it gets slower.

Comment: Yeah its about image size. User chooses the image but if i dont resize it somehow that will be a problem. What do you suggest about resizing it without using xamarin forms?

Comment: You have 2 options. 1. Resize it before you put in ImageView. 2. Set ImageView size and let system resize it. Check what option works best and then go from there

Comment: Also, why you mention forms? I don't see any forms in your code, it looks like classic.

Comment: I googled it a little bit and i didnt see any example about resizing the image without using xamarin forms thats why. ImageVıew's size is fixed. 25px to 25px its resizing it to 25 to 25 but the problem is its not losing quality and i think its the same size

Comment: You  can post separate question. May be others can help you too

Comment: Also look https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42635/what-is-they-best-way-to-load-very-large-images-on-all-3-plaforms

Comment: Thank you for your answers. ı appreciate it.