# Custom ListAdapter to display a List<> inside a ListFragment

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-listfragment, listadapter

So I am pretty new at developing for android and I decided to go with Xamarin as I like C# and I learned it first.

My actual problem surfaced 2 days ago, I have this app for which I created several fragments that display from click events listeners and such, it is a very basic app. I created a List<> that I want to use for my items in this ListFragment. I created the custom adapter like any other custom adapter I created before:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MSApp.Droid.ListClasses;

namespace MSApp.Droid
{
    public class CountryAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        public List<Country> countryList { get; set; }
        Context context;

        public CountryAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            countryList = new List<Country>();
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return countryList.Count;
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = null;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                row = inflater.Inflate(MSApp.Droid.Resource.Layout.CountryRow, parent, false);
            }
            else
            {
                row = convertView;
            }
            var countryLabel = row.FindViewById<TextView>(MSApp.Droid.Resource.Id.countryTextView);
            var countryImage = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(MSApp.Droid.Resource.Id.flagImageView);

            var data = countryList[position];

            countryLabel.Text = data.name;
            countryImage.SetImageResource(data.imageID);

            return row;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return countryList[position].id;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to create the ListFragment I cant seem to get it working together. I got something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MSApp.Droid.ListClasses;

namespace MSApp.Droid.Fragments
{
    public class CountryFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.ListFragment
    {
        private List<Country> countryList { get; set; }
        private CountryAdapter countryAdapter { get; set; }
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
            countryList = new List<Country>();
            countryList.Add(new Country() { name = "Peru", imageID = MSApp.Droid.Resource.Drawable.Peru });
            countryAdapter = new CountryAdapter(this);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

            return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
```

And that is where I get the problem, I cannot set the context to a fragment it says and I cant move forward with it, I have been looking everywhere on the internet, youtube, here, courses online, but nothing seems to use this kind of thing anywhere. If there is someone who can give me a hand with pointing me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. What does it mean - "I cant seem to get it working together"? 2. "I cannot set the context to a fragment it says and I cant move forward with it" - what is exact error and when it happens? 3. You initialise  countryList in your fragment but never pass it to adapter and you initialise another list in adapter. Which list you are trying to use? Look at my answer here how to create adapter and listview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653243/xamarin-selecting-an-image-from-gallery-and-displaying-it-in-the-listview-adapte/40661517#40661517 If that does help let me know.

Comment: Also, you are trying to use ListFragment. It is different than "regular" way. You can read here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: Yuri, What I am trying to say is that when I try to call the adapter I get it shown empty. No data even tho the list exists.

Comment: Of course. You never set you countryList inside of your adapter. If you don't fix it by Monady send me a message. I will fix it for you. Just let me know if you have to use ListFragment or just Fragment with ListView is ok

Comment: In regular Activity you pass countryList to adapter's constructor. In ListFragment you should use setListAdapter. If you want to use ListFragment I will need the code for your Activity (how you create fragment) to speed things up so I don't have to write all myself. Ideally posted dropbox or github VS solution